# When I am Installing "STRINGSIFTER", I am getting errors

Tags: string, github, portable-executable, malware, antivirus

When I am trying to install STRINGSIFTER, I am getting the following two errors:

1. Building wheel for fasttext (setup.py) ... error
2. Running setup.py install for fasttext ... error

For more details, see this picture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eNYL9ncG9emJuHSWJ-ILakI-NYzuKe-1/view?usp=sharing

link for the STRINGSIFTER: https://github.com/fireeye/stringsifter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Visual C++ installed - the error message says explicitly that.

Using text rather than an image would make it easier to see what your problem is.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But sorry, it is not working. Getting the same errors. If possible, can you please tell me any other alternative to install STRINGSIFTER in windows? I think this is my third day with these errors:)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything more, never used Stringsifter, or don't much work on Windows. I guess update the questions with the MS Visual C++ you have installed and see if anyone else can help you?

Comment: Great @Douglas Leeder, You have helped me. Initially, I have downloaded visual C++ from some other website. That time it was not working. But when I downloaded Microsoft Visual Studio C++ from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ it solved my problem. Thank you once again.